# How do I obtain the path of an executable listed in Start-up?

Tags: windows-10

In Task Manager's Start-up tab I see an item simply named 'Program'. How do I obtain the path of this .exe, so I can try to work out what it is?

[image]

Comment: right click on it and select "open file location"

Comment: Youi might also try Sysinternals' (now part of Microsoft) Autoruns, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns, which provides detailed information on *all* atuomatically run processes, far more than shown in Task Manager.

Comment: @Moab 'Open File Location' is greyed out.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that helped, thank you. I think it's a Visual Studio or SQL Server update process which will run on next reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the path via the command line you can try:
**`wmic`** (***Windows Management Instrumentation Command***).

```bat
wmic startup get command|find/i ProgramName|find "."

rem :: or get name.exe and command-line :: 

wmic startup get caption,command|findstr /b "Program Name.exe|find "."
```

---

- Output for **`steam.exe`**

```bat
>wmic startup get caption,command|findstr "steam.exe"|find "."
Steam               "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -silent
```

- One `for` loop suggestion:

```bat
for /f  tokens^=1*delims^=^"^  %i in ('wmic startup get caption^,command^|findstr "steam.exe"')do @echo\%~i ^| %~j
Steam | C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -silent
```

- Output from `for` loop:

```bat
Steam | C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -silent
```

---

- For you get the path, use **`%~dpj`**

```bat
for /f tokens^=1*delims^=^"^  %i in ('wmic startup get caption^,command^|find/i "steam"')do @echo\%i - %~dpj
```

- Output from `for` loop:

```bat
Steam - C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\
```

---

- Based on this question:
  **[Getting the arguments passed to a executable using wmic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607802/getting-the-arguments-passed-to-a-executable-using-wmic)**